# Android WebView always reporting landscape orientation

Tags: android, css, webview, media-queries, screen-orientation

We were having trouble getting media queries to properly target Android tablets when in portrait orientation for an app I am currently developing. I did some testing using http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html and discovered that Chrome works as expected when that page is loaded into it, but my app's WebView always registers as being in landscape orientation. I tried locking the activity to portrait only, to no effect. I've combed through my WebView code and AndroidManifest.xml looking for something I may have done to cause this behavior, but have come up empty. I would post relevant code, but I've been unable to find it. Google hasn't helped me so far, does anyone know what may likely be causing this issue? Any guidance on where to continue my bug search would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much hair pulling, I determined this was happening because it was reporting a height of 0px to the media query. Therefore width > height and it determined it must be a landscape orientation. I assumed it was a timing issue and moved a lot of code to onViewStateRestored but this changed nothing. The solution wound up being, of all things, to change the layout_height of my WebView from wrap_content to 0dp in the XML layout. This minor tweak apparently allowed it to determine a correct height at the right point and all media queries now target as expected.